# IF statement not work as intended. Cant get the AND to work

Tags: java, if-statement, user-input

I have two `Editext` and need them both to be true to access the second page, but even if both are false when you click on the button it accesses the second page regardless.

```
 public void DoSubmit(View view) {

        String guessSize = weight.getText().toString();
        String guessSize2 = height.getText().toString();

        if ((Integer.parseInt(guessSize) <= 20 || Integer.parseInt(guessSize) >= 200) & (Integer.parseInt(guessSize2) <= 80 || Integer.parseInt(guessSize2) >= 300) ) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter value between 20kg and 200kg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter value between 20kg and 200kg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Intent summaryActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(), secondpage.class);
            int weightkg = Integer.valueOf(weight.getText().toString());
            int heightcm = Integer.valueOf(height.getText().toString());

            summaryActivity.putExtra("weight", weightkg);
            summaryActivity.putExtra("height", heightcm);
            startActivity(summaryActivity);     // start the new page
        }
        

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use && not &. && is a logical AND, & is bitwise.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue with the OP's code. `&` does work on booleans; it just doesn't short-circuit.